# data.table row order getting messed up

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `csv` file imported as a `data.frame`. When I convert it to `data.table` by specifying the `key` as follows, the row order gets messed up.

```
setDT(DT, head1)
```

But the row order is not disturbed if convert to `data.table` as follows.

```
setDT(DT)
setkey(DT, head1)
```

Now do the following, I get a warning that says that the row orders were invalid and were corrected.

```
setDT(DT, head1)
setkey(DT, head1)

Warning message:
In setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) :
  Already keyed by this key but had invalid row order, key rebuilt.
If you didn't go under the hood please let datatable-help know so the root cause can be fixed.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You will save some time just by looking up manual of the function you are trying to use, especially examples.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `setDT`function incorrectly. The second argument is `keep.rownames`, not `key`. In addition to naming the key argument, you must also pass it as a string. Like this:

```
setDT(DT, key='head1')
```

See `?setDT` for details.